# Index was outside the bounds of the array at socket client c# code

Tags: c#, sockets

I am using server and client sockets communication provided from ([server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx)). When I running those projects from the same machine everything is working fine. When I tried to use other pc as a client I am receiving the following exception message:

> Index was outside the vounds of the array at asynchronousClient.StartClient() in line 47 which in fact is the second line:

```
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("serverIp");
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
```

**EDIT** IPHostEntry contains the name of the PC where server is stored. However ipAdress is null.

Comment: Have you stepped this code through the debugger to find out exactly what Dns.GetHostEntry is returning? It seems fairly obvious that an "Index out of bounds" error on that line, where you're trying to get item [0] by index, means that the array AddressList does not have an element zero. It would probably be far more helpful to show us more complete code, as well.

Comment: From @jeff-woods: 
0
down vote
Have you stepped this code through the debugger to find out exactly what Dns.GetHostEntry is returning? It seems fairly obvious that an "Index out of bounds" error on that line, where you're trying to get item [0] by index, means that the array AddressList does not have an element zero.

It would probably be far more helpful to show us more complete code, as well.

Comment: If (ipHostInfo.AddressLength.Length == 0) throw new Exception("No IPv6 support");

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code? GetHostEntry is used to resolve *IPs* from *names*. If the `serverIp` string actually contains an IP, this code will return at best the same IP you provided as input.

Comment: Maybe you can't get to the computer that your server is on with that IP. that can be another reason for returning nothing.

Comment: I am trying to have a client and server that communicate each other. When I tried the code in the same PC everything is working and the communication is happerning normally.

Comment: Thus @LamaTo what should I do? ipHostInfo contains the name of the pc where server is located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is raised because `ipAdress` is empty. The most likely cause for this is that the hostname exists (DNS knows about the domain), however, no A records exists. For clarification, the A in A record stands for Address and this record is used to find the address of a computer connected to the internet from a name.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of `Dns.GetHostEntry`:

> IPv6 addresses are filtered from the results of the GetHostEntry method if the local computer does not have IPv6 installed. As a result, it is possible to get back an empty IPHostEntry instance if only IPv6 results where available for the hostNameOrAddress.parameter.

Meaning, you only got back IPv6 records, and the method filtered them for you.

Comment: Thus what should I do in order not to filter the IPv6 records?

Comment: @JoseRamon As the documentation suggests, try installing IPv6 support on your machine.